# Setting in VS 2017 to prevent projects from using Roslyn by default

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I create a new web project using my visual studio 2017, it creates it with a file named packages.config which contains reference for:

> Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

```
<package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

At my work we are not allowed to use any nuget packages.
So everytime I have to manually go and uninstall Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, which will remove the packages.config file and updates my web.config file.

Is there a way I can prevent visual studio 2017 from doing this when I create a project itself?

Thank you!

Comment: @DavidG its not up to me sadly... :(

Comment: I get the restriction to avoid packages that haven't been approved, there's licensing and security to think about, but a blanket ban? That's just going to make dev slow and painful. However, the project template is just that, a template, and you can make your own set up in any way you like.

Comment: @DavidG so i need to create a new project template? is there an easy way to disable this in vs 2017?

Comment: Your easiest solution should be to modify the template.